# Scaling x-axis after IFFT-FFT

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

See the edit below for details.

I have a dataset, on which I need to perform and IFFT, cut the valueable part of it (by multiplying with a gaussian curve), then FFT back.
First is in angular frequency domain, so an IFFT leads to time domain. Then FFT-ing back should lead to angular frequency again, but I can't seem to find a solution how to get back the original domain. Of course it's easy on the y-values:

```py
yf = np.fft.ifft(y)
#cut the valueable part there..
np.fft.fft(yf)
```

For the x-value transforms I'm using [np.fft.fftfreq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) the following way:

```py
# x is in ang. frequency domain, that's the reason for the 2*np.pi division
t = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x), d=(x[1]-x[0])/(2*np.pi))
```

However doing

```py
x = np.fft.fftfreq(len(t), d=2*np.pi*(t[1]-t[0]))
```

completely not giving me back the original x values. Is that something I'm misunderstanding?

The question can be asked generalized, for example:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)

xx = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x), d = x[1]-x[0])
# how to get back the original x from xx? Is it even possible?
```

I've tried to use a temporal variable where I store the original x values, but it's not too elegant. I'm looking for some kind of inverse of fftfreq, and in general the possible best solution for that problem.
Thank you.

**EDIT**:
I will provide the code at the end.
I have a dataset which has angular frequency on x axis and intensity on the y. I want to perfrom IFFT to change to time domain. Unfortunately the x values are not
evenly spaced, so a (linear) interpolation is needed first before IFFT. Then in time domain the transform looks like this: [image: See this picture]

The next step is to cut one of the symmetrical spikes with a gaussian curve, then FFT back to angular frequency domain (the same where we started). My problem is when I transfrom the x-axis for the IFFT (which I think is correct), I can't get back into the original angular frequency domain. Here is the code, which includes the generator for the dataset too.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

C_LIGHT = 299.792

# for easier case, this is zero, so it can be ignored.
def _disp(x, GD=0, GDD=0, TOD=0, FOD=0, QOD=0):
    return x*GD+(GDD/2)*x**2+(TOD/6)*x**3+(FOD/24)*x**4+(QOD/120)*x**5

# the generator to make sample datasets
def generator(start, stop, center, delay, GD=0, GDD=0, TOD=0, FOD=0, QOD=0, resolution=0.1, pulse_duration=15, chirp=0):
    window = (np.sqrt(1+chirp**2)*8*np.log(2))/(pulse_duration**2)
    lamend = (2*np.pi*C_LIGHT)/start
    lamstart = (2*np.pi*C_LIGHT)/stop
    lam = np.arange(lamstart, lamend+resolution, resolution) 
    omega = (2*np.pi*C_LIGHT)/lam 
    relom = omega-center
    i_r = np.exp(-(relom)**2/(window))
    i_s = np.exp(-(relom)**2/(window))

    i = i_r + i_s + 2*np.sqrt(i_r*i_s)*np.cos(_disp(relom, GD=GD, GDD=GDD, TOD=TOD, FOD=FOD, QOD=QOD)+delay*omega)
    #since the _disp polynomial is set to be zero, it's just cos(delay*omega)
    return omega, i


def interpol(x,y):
    ''' Simple linear interpolation '''
    xs = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], len(x))
    intp = interp1d(x, y, kind='linear', fill_value = 'extrapolate')
    ys = intp(xs)
    return xs, ys


def ifft_method(initSpectrumX, initSpectrumY, interpolate=True):
    if len(initSpectrumY) > 0 and len(initSpectrumX) > 0:
        Ydata = initSpectrumY
        Xdata = initSpectrumX
    else:
        raise ValueError
    N = len(Xdata)
    if interpolate:
        Xdata, Ydata = interpol(Xdata, Ydata)
        # the (2*np.pi) division is because we have angular frequency, not frequency
        xf = np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=(Xdata[1]-Xdata[0])/(2*np.pi)) * N * Xdata[-1]/(N-1)
        yf = np.fft.ifft(Ydata)
    else:
        pass # some irrelevant code there
    return xf, yf

def fft_method(initSpectrumX ,initSpectrumY):
    if len(initSpectrumY) > 0 and len(initSpectrumX) > 0:
        Ydata = initSpectrumY
        Xdata = initSpectrumX
    else:
        raise ValueError
    yf = np.fft.fft(Ydata)
    xf = np.fft.fftfreq(len(Xdata), d=(Xdata[1]-Xdata[0])*2*np.pi)
    # the problem is there, where I transform the x values.
    xf = np.fft.ifftshift(xf)
    return xf, yf 


# the generated data
x, y = generator(1, 3, 2, delay = 1500, resolution = 0.1) 

# plt.plot(x,y)

xx, yy = ifft_method(x,y)

#if the x values are correctly scaled, the two symmetrical spikes should appear exactly at delay value
# plt.plot(xx, np.abs(yy))

#do the cutting there, which is also irrelevant now

# the problem is there, in fft_method. The x values are not the same as before transforms.
xxx, yyy = fft_method(xx, yy) 
plt.plot(xxx, np.abs(yyy))

#and it should look like this:
#xs = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], len(x))
#plt.plot(xs, np.abs(yyy))

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `fftfreq` does not compute an FFT. All it does is describe the x-axis of the FFT output. You cannot use it to determine the x-axis of the IFFT.

Comment: I'm know that it does not compute FFT. np.fft.fft does. I'm interested in the correct transformations of the x-axis.

Comment: Try to generate a synthetic example with the approximate form of your dataset. E.g. your spectrum is likely real. Then others can easily run this. Look up https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's quite long to explain, but I'll edit the post soon.

Comment: I added a reproducible example.